# Why do braces around a single-letter argument of a macro affect its output?

Tags: macros, braces, syntax, arguments

I thought `\ul 8`, `\ul8`, and `\ul{8}` are identical ways of passing an argument `8` to a command `\ul`. However, they produce different output. Why?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{soul}

\newcommand\A\ul
\newcommand\B[1]{\ul#1}
\newcommand\C[1]{\ul{#1}}

\begin{document}

Text \ul8 using \verb|\ul8|

Text \A8 using \verb|\A8|

Text \B8 using \verb|\B8|

Text \C8 using \verb|\C8|

Text \ul{8} using \verb|\ul{8}|

Text \A{8} using \verb|\A{8}|

Text \B{8} using \verb|\B{8}|

Text \C{8} using \verb|\C{8}|

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: They would, if `\ul` were a command taking an argument; the situation here is more complex than it appears. Think to `\ul` as a box making command, where braces are mandatory.

Comment: @egreg Thank you! Funny. `\makebox8`, `\framebox8` work just fine. So I guess `\ul` looks for its argument on its own, not relying on TeX's argument passing mechanism.

Comment: I added an explanation with references to the package documentation.

Comment: Maybe the package should warn about the case when instead of a brace a token that is not a control sequence follows.

Comment: @egreg Instead of a warning, it can treat a non-`{` as a single-letter argument, i.e., `\ul8` can be treated as a special case equivalent to `\ul{8}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The command `\ul` is an alias to `\textul`, but this is not the main thing; the definition of `\textul` is

```
\DeclareRobustCommand*\textul{\SOUL@ulsetup\SOUL@}
```

which makes clear it is *not* a command taking an argument; in turn `\SOUL@` is defined by

```
\def\SOUL@{\futurelet\SOUL@@\SOUL@expand}
```

The description of this macro in the `.dtx` file says

> This macro is the entry to `soul`. Using it does only make sense after setting up a soul driver. The next token after the `soul` command will be assigned to `\SOUL@@`. This can be some text enclosed in braces, or the name of a macro that contains text.

This is also explained in the user documentation, at the start of section 2:

> The `soul` package provides five commands that are aimed at emphasizing text parts. Each of the commands takes one argument that can either be the text itself or the name of a macro that contains text (e.g. `\so\text`). See table 1 for a complete command survey.

So `\ul8` not working is expected (and documented).

Comment: What I was trying to achieve was to rename `\hl` to `\?`, which is more convenient to type, and use `\??` to quickly mark a doubtful place to be checked later, or `\?{some comment}`. It works fine with `\?` mapped to `\colorbox`, but apparently cannot be done with `\hl`, right?

Comment: OK, I think this can be achieved simply with `\ifthenelse`, by conditionally using a `\colorbox` or `\hl`.